# Need help understanding this this function

Tags: arrays, vb.net, bounds, computation, reflex

```
Dim i as Long, arr(5) As Long

for i = 1 to 6
    arr(i-1) = i-1
next 
console.writeLine(arr(LBound(arr)+5) + arr(UBound(arr)-2))
```

I understand the output is 8 but could someone explain why it is 8, Lbound and UBound, this type of question comes up in my exam, and i am having some issue with getting my head around this.

Much appreciated

Comment: A short little google about `vb.net ubound` gave me on the second link (this may vary at your computer) the microsoft documentation of the function UBound.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(arr(LBound(arr) + 5) + arr(UBound(arr) - 2))` will equal 8 as `lbound(arr) = 0 + 5 and ubound(arr)` = 5 - 2 = 3.
lbound gets left most number in array so be 0 in your case and you added a 5 and Ubound gets the highest bascailly so be a 5 - 2

and finally add the results together = 5 + 3 = 8!

Comment: In `arr(LBound(arr)) => arr(0)` you put `0 => (1 -1)` Then add `5 => (0 + 5)`. In `arr(UBound(arr)) => arr(5)` you put `5 => (6 - 1)`. Then, you subtract `2 => (5 - 2)`. So you have `(0 + 5) + (5 - 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

UBOUND means "Upper Boundary" in VB.  It returns the sequence number for the last item (the upper boundary) of an array.  LBOUND is for the lower boundary or first item.

I don't typically use them these days as VB.Net has easier to use options to do the same thing.

your loop builds this array

```
arr(0)=0 
arr(1)=1 
arr(2)=2 
arr(3)=3 
arr(4)=4 
arr(5)=5
```

Now `LBound(arr)` here returns 0, and the `ubound(arr)` returns 5.

now, if you array was this:

```
arr(0)=10
arr(1)=11
arr(2)=12
arr(3)=13
arr(4)=14
arr(5)=15
```

Then `LBound(arr)` still returns 0, and the `ubound(arr)` returns 5.

[UBOUND FUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function)

[LBOUND FUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/lbound-function)

Comment: Very good explanation and example! may i suggest add in 2 references for future users!
UBOUND: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function


LBOUND: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/lbound-function